# Unity: Ball falls through object that is rotating around another object

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, collision

Imagine you have a ball falling due to gravity. When it encounters a rotating "cube" object, then you would expect it to bounce off of the object. However, in my case if the cube is rotating fast, the ball goes through it, but if the cube is rotating slowly, the ball hits it and bounces away as expected.

I am using RotateAround() inside the Update() method to achieve the "cube" object's rotation. I tried setting the ball's collision detection to Discrete, Continuous, and Continuous Dynamic with no luck.

My goal is to make the ball bounce away no matter how fast the "cube" object is rotating around another object.

Is there something else I should look into?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try lowering the `Fixed Timestep` value under `Edit > Project Settings > Time`.

Be aware that this will affect the performance of the game as you're calculating physics more often.

Documentation: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html

Also, I assume that you have box and sphere colliders as opposed to mesh colliders? The former are more efficient at detecting collisions.